# If I have a partial type for a builder. How do I then type it when complete?

Tags: typescript

How do I use types when I want to build an object?

EG. If I have:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: string;
}

interface Bar extends Partial<Foo>{}

const foo: Foo = useMemo(() => {
  const bar: Bar = {}
  bar.a = 'a';
  bar.b = 'b';
  bar.c = 'c';
  return bar;
,[])
```

only this results in a type error:

```
Type 'Partial<Foo>' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
  Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not a
```

Comment: this is expected isnt it? but cant you just use type assertion? `const bar: Foo = {} as Foo` ?

Comment: @Estradiaz  I'm new to Typescript. Clearly I'm over thinking it!

Comment: Any reason to construct the object this way? (vs doing `const bar = { a: 'a' ... }`)

Comment: @AlekseyL.I'm just simplifying the example, The real one has some complex calculations

Comment: Then `const bar = {} as Foo` and drop the partial.. Or better extract complex parts to functions and construct the object in one go

Comment: Be aware that using a type assertion in this case is not safe. If someone adds a property to `Foo` later there will be no compiler error helping you catch the missing assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the properties are complex to create, i would recommend storing them in locals first and then returning the correct type directly:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: string;
}

const foo: Foo = useMemo(() => {
  const a = 'a';
  const b = 'b';
  const c = 'c';
  const d = 'd';

  return { a, b, c, d };
},[])
```